# how to use Meteor.http.call

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to send sms using Meteor.http.call.I take two errors:

> First error:When page loaded,**"WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/632/i0uapg48/websocket' failed: WebSocket
>   is closed before the connection is established."**
>
> Second error:when I click ebultenkydet,**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'call' of undefined"**

```
Template.footerLayout.events({
'click #ebultenkaydet': function(e, template) {
var auth_url="http://api.sorentesms.com/index.php"
var result = Meteor.http.call("POST", auth_url, {
data: {
              'apiNo':'1',
              'user':'test',
              'pass':'test123',

              'message':'hi',
              'number':'+905075587***',
              'from':'test',

           },
           headers: {
                 "content-type":"application/json",
                 "Accept":"application/json"
           },
         })
         }
 });
```

Can you help me about it?
Thank you all

Comment: Not sure about the first error but unless you're using an old version of Meteor it's `HTTP.call('POST','url'...)` or `HTTP.post('url' ...)`, not `Meteor.http.call`. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http

Comment: yes First error is solved,thank you for hel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending your http request inside a client side block, and `Meteor.http` is only available on sever side. You have to put this block in a Meteor.isServer block.

Don't forget to `meteor add http` to able to use the code:

Let me rewrite your code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    authCall: function () {
      this.unblock(); // Make sure server doesn't get block from this call
      var auth_url="http://api.sorentesms.com/index.php";
      return Meteor.http.call("POST", auth_url, {
        data: {
          'apiNo':'1',
          'user':'test',
          'pass':'test123',
          'message':'hi',
          'number':'+905075587***',
          'from':'test',
        },
        headers: {
          "content-type":"application/json",
          "Accept":"application/json"
        },
      })
    }
  });
}


Template.footerLayout.events({
'click #ebultenkaydet': function(e, template) {
    Meteor.call("authCall", function(error, results) {
        console.log(results); //results.data should be a JSON object
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what version of Meteor this is but `HTTP.call` is actually available on client and server (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call), the problem here was that there was no callback so `result` would have been undefined. However given the user/pass in the api call, doing it on the server is probably the right thing to do in this case...

Comment: There is no callback because you violate CORS when you do call to another domain

Comment: @jwall Hi there I need abit of help with the way my Meteor HTTP.call() is handling the response. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065295/how-do-i-modify-my-http-call-so-that-it-returns-relevant-information?noredirect=1#comment77118740_45065295